# Where do I ask a question with no obvious site?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question on Microsoft Partner Network benefits but I can't find an obvious site to ask the question without probably getting down-votes. Should I just pick a site and hope for the best?

My question is,

> My company is a member of the Microsoft Partner Network (MPN) and I would like to submit a Windows Azure technical support ticket using these benefits, something we've never done before. When trying to submit a technical support ticket through Azure's support system, via a Program Benefits Support link that's specifically meant for MPN members, it leads me to a dead end by asking for an Account ID and Contract ID which I don't know.
>
> I have tried to contact both the MPN support and Azure billing support channels to understand how to proceed past this, but both support channels are referring me to the other support channel. I am stuck in an endless support feedback loop
>
> Where or how can I obtain the Account ID and Contract ID?

I am questioning whether any SE sites can help me with this question, not trying to decide for MPN whether they should or shouldn't be using SE as their support system.

Comment: You should probably quote what you want to ask here, and then ask (in *this* question) which is the most appropriate site.  If you're told there is *no* appropriate site, abide by that (as in, don't post it at all on the SE network).  You could always of course start or support an Area 51 proposal.

Comment: From the sound of it, perhaps software recommendations... Maybe...

Comment: @bummi I've elaborated in my question.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but for me it's still not clear what's the topic you want to ask for. Is it programming related (might fit for SO), is it a license question (might fit nowhere, maybe programmers), a network question and so on... Could you give an example?

Comment: You say "*My company is a member of the MPN*...". Well, how do you know that? Who told you so? Ask *that* guy what your account ID and contract ID are. If *he* doesn't know, ask him who would know. If doesn't know that either, ask him how *he* knows your "*company is a member of the MPN*". In other words, investigate *internally*, within your own company, rather than continuing to chase your tail with MS, who clearly don't know how to help you in your current circumstances. With all that said, I don't know which stack this question belongs on, or whether it belongs on any stack at all.

Comment: @bummi This is probably closest to being a licensing question.

Comment: @AlanM Despite bummi's hedged comment above, I don't think Programmers would welcome this question (they're mostly focused on conceptual questions related to programming, CS, etc).

Comment: What's your actual question? I'm wondering whether this might be appropriate for [startups.se], but as it stands, I'm not completely sure what you'd want answered. Are you asking if others have had this experience? Where you can find your account and contract ID? What alternatives there might be?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I've updated the question again, however my real desire is to know where to post it, if anywhere. I don't think it's start-up related. Some kind of site on interactions with Microsoft or conducting business as a Microsoft partner would be ideal if one existed.

Comment: @AlanM I know. It's a bit of a stretch for Startups, but we'd definitely take it if it was the same question, but about BizSpark instead of MPN. So I figured maybe we could for this. But it is a tough call. I don't know of anywhere else in SE that would take this.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I would accept your last comment as an answer.

Comment: @AlanM I could post one, but I'm definitely not the definitive source of information on Stack Exchange sites. It might be worth holding off a bit and seeing if anyone else has any suggestions. New sites spin up pretty quickly, so it's possible there's a site, or even just a proposal, that would be a perfect match.

Comment: I've added this as a sample question in the Ask Microsoft Area 51 site to see if it gets any traction, see  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80369/ask-microsoft/86372#86372.

Comment: Yes, nowhere here.  If your company is a member of the MPN (mine is as well) you can easily contact a rep and ask them this question.  You'll get an answer pretty quickly.  Just find out who the primary contact is at your company and route your query through them.